What does "CD military" mean on this sign at this crossing point between East Berlin and West Berlin? (June/July 1989)
I read "CD military" on this sign at this crossing point between East Berlin and West Berlin in June/July 1989:

Image source: https://youtu.be/QCy2DqPt9Gk?t=1272
What does "CD military" mean on this sign at this crossing point between East Berlin and West Berlin?

This is the east German crossing point GÜSt Zimmerstraße on the Friedrichstraße / Zimmerstraße.
As general rule, you entered and left in the driving direction (right hand side).
The upper pedestrian sign, tells the pedestrians to cross over to the right hand side.
The lower pedestrian sign, tells members of the diplomatic corps (Corps Diplomatique) or of the (Allied) military that they may use the left hand side since they are not subject to customs controls.
